# Yarn add creates yarn.lock and node_modules folder inside sub-package in yarn workspace

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I am using a yarn workspace, and wonder why yarn creates a `yarn.lock` and a `node_modules` folder in the sub-projects when adding dependencies via `yarn add ...`.

As an example, imagine the following simple yarn workspace:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "workspaces: [
    "./packages/*"
  ]
}
```

File structure with sub-project named "subpackage".

[image]

Then I add a dependency to the "subpackage" using the following command:

```
yarn workspace subpackage add lodash
```

After that, the file folders change as follows:

[image]

I wonder why yarn creates the `yarn.lock` and the `node_modules` folder when I am in a workspace and even explicitly use the workspace version of the add command. Shouldn't all dependencies be managed through the root workspace directory?

I didn't really find a clear answer to this in the yarn documentation, however this [blog-post](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/blog/2017/08/02/introducing-workspaces/), which introduced the workspace feature, clearly confirms the expected behaviour:

> If you want to modify a dependency of a Workspace, just run the
> appropriate command inside the Workspace folder:
>
> ```
> $ cd packages/jest-matcher-utils/
> $ yarn add left-pad
> ✨ Done in 1.77s.
> $ git status
> modified: package.json
> modified: ../../yarn.lock
> ```
>
> Note that Workspaces don’t have their own yarn.lock files, and the
> root yarn.lock contains all the dependencies for all the Workspaces.
> When you want to change a dependency inside a Workspace, the root
> yarn.lock will be changed as well as the Workspace’s package.json.

Comment: I don't think I have a yarnrc.yml - should I? I am using yarn v1.22.10 :)

Comment: The workaround I am using is crazy, installing them, removing `node_modules` and `yarn.lock` files, again `yarn install`.

Comment: Yeah, I did the same actually...